# не могу установить agile плагин для redmine

Tags: ruby, redmine

все делал по инструкции

```
    alexey@mx:/var/www/html/redmine$ sudo bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production
    (in /usr/share/redmine)
    rake aborted!
    Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

gemfile

```
seen_adapters = {}
Dir['{config,instances/*/config}/database.yml'].select do |f|
  File.exists?(f)
end.each do |database_file|
  database_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result)
  adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq
  if adapters.any?
    adapters.each do |adapter|
      next if seen_adapters[adapter]
      seen_adapters[adapter] = true
      case adapter
      when 'mysql2'
        gem "mysql2", "~> 0.4.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when 'mysql'
        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when /postgresql/
        gem "pg", "~> 0.18.1", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when /sqlite3/
        gem "sqlite3", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "jdbc-sqlite3", ">= 3.8.10.1", :platforms => :jruby
        gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when /sqlserver/
        gem "tiny_tds", "~> 0.6.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      else
        warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")
      end
    end
  else
    warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")
  end
end
```

sudo gem install mysql2

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170212-3499-mqg2bh.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.5/gem_make.out
```

Comment: по какой инструкции? mysql2 установлен?

Comment: добавьте в gem фаил mysql2, он же пишет чего ему не хватает

Comment: я в руби не разбираюсь. Выложил файл gem из /usr/share/redmine/gemfile.

Comment: по какой инструкции устанавливали?

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить пакет `ruby-dev` в систему, `apt-get`'ом.

Comment: да. спасибо помогло!